# Create (and fill out) a new column based on string detection

Tags: r

I have a data set of tweets and I want to search for names within the tweet and then fill out a new column based on the name match. so for example if tweets$text == "Thanks, Obama", then I want a new column to fill out as tweets$party == "Obama".

I have managed to create a working code for when there are only two names to be searched for:

```
library(tidyverse)
users <- read_csv("http://nodeassets.nbcnews.com/russian-twitter-trolls/users.csv")

tweets$party <- NA #create a new column for party name
clinton <- c("Clinton", "Hillary", "Hillary Clinton")
trump <- c("Donald", "Trump", "Donald Trump")

party_tweets <- tweets %>% 
  filter(str_detect(text, trump) | str_detect(text, clinton)) #filter the tweets so only ones relating to the party remain
party_tweets$party <- grepl(clinton, party_tweets$text) == T #detect whether tweet contains name or not 

party_tweets$party [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Clinton"
party_tweets$party [party_tweets$party == "FALSE"] <- "Trump"
```

This works fine. However, I now want to detect for the names of other politicians (not just two). I've tried a number of attempts with str_detect, if_else and grepl functions but haven't been able to get anything satisfactory.

For example:

```
clinton <- c("Clinton", "Hillary", "Hillary Clinton")
trump <- c("Donald", "Trump", "Donald Trump")
obama <- c("Barack", "Obama", "Barack Obama")
sanders <- c("Bernie", "Sanders", "Bernie Sanders")
politicians <- c(clinton, trump, obama, sanders)


party_tweets <- tweets %>% 
  filter(str_detect(text, politicians))
party_tweets$party <- str_extract(party_tweets$text, politicians))
```

doesn't work.

I've tried using grepl to show true if a politician is mentioned and then made a new column with the value, as follows:

```
party_tweets <- tweets %>% 
  filter(str_detect(text, politicians)) #filter the tweets so only ones relating to the party remain

party_tweets$politicians <- NA

#Reassign clinton tweets
party_tweets$party <- grepl(clinton, party_tweets$text) == T #detect whether tweet contains name or not 
party_tweets$politician [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Clinton"

#Reassing Trump tweets
party_tweets$party <- grepl(trump, party_tweets$text) == T 
party_tweets$politician [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Trump"

#Reassign Obama tweets
party_tweets$party <- grepl(obama, party_tweets$text) == T  
party_tweets$politician [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Obama"

#Reassign Sanders tweets
party_tweets$party <- grepl(sanders, party_tweets$text) == T 
party_tweets$politician [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Sanders"


party_tweets %>% 
  count(politician, sort = T)
```

This showed only 2276 Trump mentions, when

```
table(str_detect(tweets$text, "Trump"))
```

shows TRUE equals 37809.

In short (I appreciate this may be confusing but trying to provide as much info as possible) tweets$text column has the contents of the tweet, I want to detect if a politicians name is mentioned and then if so fill the tweets$party column with the name. I feel there is probably a straightforward solution to this and is just a matter of knowing the function, so if I am missing something obvious or anyone has any pointers I'd be very grateful. If anything is unclear let me know and I'll clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, I recently wrestled with the pattern argument on a different function. Investigate using OR (the `|`). For example:  `clinton <- c("Clinton|Hillary|Hillary Clinton")`.

Comment: Exactly, the `str_extract` approach you tried above should work if you first do: `politicians <- paste(politicians, collapse = "|")`

Comment: I would also add an `ignore.case = TRUE` argument to your grepl() statements, to capture missing cases when people do not capitalise politicians' names.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use evaluation twice in your code:

> `party_tweets$party <- grepl(clinton, party_tweets$text) == T #detect whether tweet contains name or not`

grepl() returns the Boolean vector of the same length as an evaluated vector.Then you select `== T`, which is redundant because it would return the same vector. You don't have to do that, if you are checking for `==TRUE` values later on:

> `party_tweets$politician [party_tweets$party == "TRUE"] <- "Clinton"`

so, just get rid of `==T` part in the first line of your look-up.

Edit: you don't need to wrap Boolean values into the brackets